# Mongoose populating an object inside an object inside an object inside an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Hello my problem is quite difficult. Please help. This is my cart. I am using a query that's failing me:

```
interface CartInterface extends Document {
    products: Array<{
        quantity: number,
        productDetails: PopulatedDoc<ProductInterface>
    }>,
}
```

I used this query: `Cart.findById(req.params.id).populate('products.productDetails')` but it's wrong. I need to go inside each array and find each object

I need to populate all arrays so **products[index].productDetails**.

I populated **products.productsArray** easily last time quite easily last time when my schema was like this:

```
interface CartInterface extends Document {
    productsArray: Array<PopulatedDoc<ProductInterface>>
}
```

I used this query:
`Cart.findById(req.params.id).populate('productsArray')`